# Dividing DataFrame with a key

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a big CSV file(with over 7milion records) with 30 columns, where the some of data in columns are short codes as for example "ORD" or numbers of months from 1 to 12.
I want to write a loop that will divide this csv file to smaller ones on a given key, for example i would like to create 12CSVs with name as the key for the months(that means my_csv_1.CSV, my_csv_2.CSV etc) or every code(my_csv_code1.CSV,my_csv_code2.CSV etc)

Here is my try:

```
for i in range(1,len(my_csv.Month.unique())+1):
    my_csv_i = my_csv[(my_csv['Month'] == i) | (my_csv['Month']==i)]
    my_csv_i.to_csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby`:

```
for k,g in df.groupby('Month'):
    g.to_csv('my_csv_{}.csv'.format(k))
```